# Get reference to parameter inside a Lambda passed as a Func

Tags: c#, lambda, func

Given the following set of classes:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}    

public class ObjectProcessor
{
    public int ProcessObject(MyClass myClass)
    {
        return myClass.MyInt ++;
    } 
}

public class Runner
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var classToPass = new MyClass();

        FuncExecutor.ExecuteAction<MyClass>(x => x.ProcessObject(classToPass));
    }
}

public static class FuncExecutor
{
    public static void ExecuteAction<T>(Expression<Func<ObjectProcessor, int>> expression)
    {
        // var func = expression.Compile(); ... does having an Expression help?

        // How can I get a reference to 'classToPass' at this point?

        // The 'classToPass' Type is known to be 'T', in this case 'MyClass'.
    }
}
```

From within the `ExecuteAction` method, how can I get a reference to the `classToPass` instance that was passed in to `ProcessObject`?

**EDIT:** The comments have highlighted the complexity of trying to parse Expression Trees which could vary widely in their composition.

However, in this particular case there are two facts which cut down this variation considerably:

- `ProcessObject` will only ever take a single parameter.
- The parameter type is known in advance.

Code altered to express this.

Comment: You can crawl through the expression tree and find the `ConstantExpression`.  How to do that depends on how much the structure of the tree may vary.

Comment: This might be one of the cases where a completely different approach might be better than trying to force a solution using expression trees.

Comment: @Dirk, can you explain further what you mean?

Comment: It's often refered to as the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking about a problem you are asking about what you think would be a good solution. Of course this is just my opinion based on the small code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer very specifically:

```
public class Runner
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var classToPass = new MyClass();
        classToPass.MyInt = 42;

        FuncExecutor.ExecuteAction(x => x.ProcessObject(classToPass));
    }
}

public class FuncExecutor
{
    public static void ExecuteAction(Expression<Func<ObjectProcessor, int>> expression)
    {
        var lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)expression;
        var methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)lambdaExpression.Body;

        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)methodCallExpression.Arguments[0];
        var constantExpression = (ConstantExpression)memberExpression.Expression;
        var fieldInfo = (FieldInfo)memberExpression.Member;

        var myClassReference = (MyClass) fieldInfo.GetValue(constantExpression.Value);

        Console.WriteLine(myClassReference.MyInt); // prints "42"
    }
}
```

Please note that when you pass the lambda to the `ExecuteAction` method, you capture a local variable reference (`classToPass`). The compiler will generate some code to handle that properly. More precisely, it will generate a type with a single member (a field) of type `MyClass` to hold the reference and use it from this point. That's why you'll get a `MemberExpression` in the argument expression list.

Since you can't directly manipulate this generated type, you can't just use the member expression `Value` property. But you can dynamically invoke the member accessor using the `MemberInfo` and the target reference (an instance of the compiler generated type).

I would not rely on this code.

You can read more about lambda related compiler generated code here, for example: http://thewalkingdev.blogspot.fr/2012/04/c-lambda-expressions-and-closures.html

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to pass the instance as parameter and let ExecuteAction take care of calling the process method using that instance. To do this it is necessary to give your code a little bit of structure using a generic object processor interface:

```
public interface IObjectProcessor<T> {
    public int ProcessObject(T instance);
}

public class MyClassProcessor : IObjectProcessor<MyClass> {
    public int ProcessObject(MyClass myClass) {
        return myClass.MyInt ++;
    }
}

public class Runner {
    public void Run() {
        var classToPass = new MyClass();
        var processor = new MyClassProcessor();

        FuncExecutor.ExecuteAction<MyClass>(processor, classToPass);
    }
}

public class FuncExecutor {
    public static void ExecuteAction<T>(IObjectProcessor<T> processor, T obj) {
        int result = processor.ProcessObject(obj);
    }
}
```

This design could be a little annoying especially if your processor are "stateless" and if you really need a Func as parameter. In this case you can drop the interface and use static processors:

```
public class MyClassProcessor
    public static int ProcessObject(MyClass myClass) {
        return myClass.MyInt ++;
    }
}

public class Runner {
    public void Run() {
        var classToPass = new MyClass();

        FuncExecutor.ExecuteAction<MyClass>(MyClassProcessor.ProcessObject, classToPass);
    }
}

public class FuncExecutor {
    public static void ExecuteAction<T>(Func<T, int> process, T obj) {
        int result = process(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I ended up doing until a pure expression based solution was posted in a different answer.